# fswatch-ing a list of files, make-ing only the changed ones

Tags: makefile, fswatch

Here's a minimal makefile for using pandoc to compile `md` to `pdf`. The `make watch` command watches for changed `md` files (using [`fswatch`](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch)) and triggers `make` if so.

```
SRCS=$(wildcard *.md)
PDFS=$(SRCS:.md=.pdf)

all:    $(PDFS)

%.pdf: %.md
    @pandoc $< -o $@

watch: $(SRCS)
    @fswatch -o $^ | xargs -n1 -I{} make
```

Currently, `watch` isn't very selective: even if just one `md` file is changed, it builds *all* possible targets (everything in `PDFS`). I would like a version of this code that watches all the `md` files for changes, but only builds a `pdf` for the *changed* `md` files. (I realize this is kind of pointless for the present case, but it's useful in another, more complicated use case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
@fswatch -0 $^ | xargs -0 -n1 sh -c 'ALT=`basename "$$1"`; make $${ALT/.md/.pdf}' _
```

`$$1` ends up identified with `/path/to/changed_file.md` as returned by `fswatch`. A couple string manipulations give `changed_file.pdf`, which is fed to `make`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass the target you want to be recreated as the goal target on the command line?

```
@fswatch -o $^ | xargs -n1 -I{} $(MAKE) '{}'
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work: make[1]: *** No rule to make target `1'.  Stop.

Comment: I guess you shouldn't really need the `{}`.  Well, I don't know how fswatch works.  Clearly something is not as expected with it's output (for example, it's not just printing a list of files that have been modified one filename per line).  I recommend you add the `-t` or `--verbose` option to `xargs` and look at what the xargs command is actually invoking.  Also you should run the `fswatch` command by itself from the shell prompt and look at the output it's generating.

Comment: I just looked at the online docs: http://emcrisostomo.github.io/fswatch/doc/1.9.3/fswatch.html/Tutorial-Introduction-to-fswatch.html#Detecting-File-System-Changes  You don't want the `-o` option, clearly.  That just prints the number of changes.  You want the main mode which prints the files that actually changed.